# Gitlab stubbornly uses default configuration values for Postgresql database

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-7, gitlab-8

context: Gitlab 8 with external nginx and postgresql on Ubuntu 15.04. It all worked with Gitlab 7.10 and I started with a fresh install to avoid upgrade-problems.

In the gitlab.rb there is:

```
gitlab_rails['db_adapter'] = "postgresql"
gitlab_rails['db_encoding'] = "unicode"
gitlab_rails['db_database'] = "gitlabdb"
gitlab_rails['db_pool'] = 10
gitlab_rails['db_username'] = "gitlab"
```

When doing a reconfigure and "gitlab-rake gitlab:setup" there is no problem, and the database gets recreated. So far looking good. Unfortunately the page doesn't load and I get a 500 - the logfile tells me that it cannot login with the given password. I made the database accept all (without password) and then got to the weird error:

```
ActiveRecord::NoDatabaseError (FATAL:  database "gitlabhq_production" does not exist
```

Nowhere in the config-files a database gitlabhq_production is mentioned, so I'm clueless here. Can you help out?

Comment: Can  you confirm which installation method you are using, what OS along with version and what steps you followed when you did the new install?

Comment: Installed from 14.04 deb, put "nginx['enable'] = false" and "postgresql['enable'] = false" and followed http://www.sapph.ca/blog/2015/06/21/How-To-Install-GitLab-on-Ubuntu-15-04/

Answer (score 0):

It was an old instance of Gitlab bugging. A reboot helped.